# Unable to use Pig udf

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to PIG and I wrote a UDF in java and copied and used the following commands to compile the java class with pig-version.jar (I am using pig-0.11.1 and hadoop-1.2.1).

```
>cd udfs
>java -cp $PIG_HOME/pig-0.11.1.jar UPPER.java
```

It prompted me with the following lines

Note: UPPER.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

I though its just a warning and built a jar file for udfs folder

```
 >jar -cf udfs.jar udfs
```

Then I ran the following pig script some.pig

```
  REGISTER udfs.jar;
    DEFINE udfs.UPPER();
    A= load 'input' using PigStorage(',') as (fname:chararray,lname:chararray,age:int);
    B = foreach A generate udfs.UPPER(fname);
    store B into 'some-output3' using PigStorage(',');
```

I ran the script using command

```
 >pig -x local some.pig
```

It gave me the following error

```
 Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

    2014-02-22 12:50:28,524 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.11.1 (r1459641)    compiled Mar 22 2013, 02:13:53
    2014-02-22 12:50:28,525 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to:  /home/vamshi23/pig-area/pig_1393102228520.log
    2014-02-22 12:50:28,985 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /root/.pigbootup not found
    2014-02-22 12:50:29,273 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///
    2014-02-22 12:50:30,374 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <file  some.pig, line 3, column 11>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '.'
    Details at logfile: /home/vamshi23/pig-area/pig_1393102228520.log
```

Could someone please help me resolve this issue?

Thank you,
Vamshi

Comment: From [this post](http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/how-to-run-pig-script-through-command-line/) it looks like you can try just running `pig ./some.pig`

Comment: What does line 3 of `some.pig` look like?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be in your usage of [DEFINE](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#define-udfs).  Your usage of it should appear like this:

```
DEFINE Upper udfs.UPPER();
```

The first part is the alias that you use to reference the UDF later.

You can then use it like this:

```
B = foreach A generate Upper(fname);
```

Note that Pig already has an [UPPER](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#upper) UDF defined.  I'm not sure if this will cause a conflict so I changed the casing, which I think avoids this.

You should also be able to use your UPPER UDF without defining it first.  Just remove the line where you invoke DEFINE and use what you originally had:

```
B = foreach A generate udfs.UPPER(fname);
```

Check out the Pig documentation on UDFs [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/udf.html) for more info.